# Input validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I've got two input forms:

```
<input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" />
<input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/>
```

this first input (name) shouldn't accept empty field or the many spaces, and the second input (email) should contain only one (@) and at least one dot(.)

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: Your tag only shows "javascript" though this can be done in just HTML5. Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: You're asking for very basic and well-documented form validation. Answers to your question will be widely available via a search engine or SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding, you are trying to write a form that needs to validate an email address input. If I am right, then you need to validate the email input in javascript. See the code [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/a9pc6fsg/).

JS function to validate email with regex that I used in the jsFiddle demo:

```
function validateEmail(email) {     
  var re =/\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
  return re.test(email);
}
```

Comment: will you include some instructions from that link in this post? This answer, as is, is pretty close to a "link only" answer.  From, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, >Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it with HTML 5

```
<input id="email" class="input" name="email" value="" size="30" type="email" required />
```